# Angular tries to import NestJS modules in NX monorepo

Tags: angular, nestjs

so I have run into an annoying issue. I am using a monorepo with Angular and NestJS. I did the stupid think of including NestJS files on the client side (just to have access to DTOs). Angular would not compile because there where dependancies on core NestJS modules in files that I had imported. I removed all such dependancies and put them in a shared lib. But nonetheless, Angular still does not compile, showin the following error:

```
./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:10:15-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/home/panos/code/netstate-master/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes'
```

I am alsmost certain that there are no client -> NestJS deps now, so I am not sure how to solve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. I was importing the Injectable from the nest core module instead of angular in a couple of my files. Easy mistake to make and it'll cost you a couple of hours :(